# Show route view in modals

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i want to show this
Route::resource('tags', 'TagsController');
in this modal

```
<div class="modal" id="modaldemo9">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content modal-content-demo">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6 class="modal-title">Supprimer tags </h6><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                                        type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `Route::resource('tags', 'TagsController');` will generate 7 routes. Which one do you want to show in modal?

Comment: index routes of tags

Comment: If you are using javascript on frontend then you can make a GET request to the index route when the modal is triggered and then insert the response in `<div class="modal-body"> ... </div>` either by returning a html string as response from the server or returning json response from the server if you are using a framework like react or vue - in latter case you make a component for the index view in react or vue and then hydrate the response json data in the component.

Comment: @tahadahni please answer questions for clarification in the question with an [edit]. Comments are not part of the Q&A.

Comment: @Donkarnash that comment sounds like most of an answer.

Comment: @clvrmnky Ha ha yeah.  Initially thought about writing it as an answer but was awaiting more details from OP. Can still write it as an answer if you think it could benefit future visitors. :)

Comment: @clvrmnky Na I don't think there's enough context available as per SO standard.  And it's not about rep. Have experienced that newbies on SO, when they don't see answer(s), they just think that the solution hasn't been found - don't care to go through comments.